# My mouse & keyboard aren't working when plugged into my KVM Switch

Tags: windows, usb, switch, kvm-switch

I have two computers connected to a brand new KVM Switch (CKL-923HUA). Both computers are running Windows 10. I can switch between the displays without any issue, but the Keyboard, Mouse, and Headphone Jacks are not working when I plug my peripherals into the KVM Switch.

When I plug them directly into either computer, they work without issue. And when plugged into the switch, both the keyboard and mouse have lights indicating that they are powered on. I also made sure to use the special HDMI/USB cables that came with the switch.

I've been searching online for hours and tried many different steps. I've restarted everything, unplugged and replugged, but I can't get the mouse and keyboard to work when going though the switch. Neither computer can detect the headphones when they are plugged into the switch either. Currently I'm stuck manually switching everything back and forth between computers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read through this article below. There are different kinds of KVM switches and not all are created equal.   https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/152165-desktop-loses-mouse-keyb-on-usb-kvm

Comment: If it never worked why don't you engage the company or contact amazon for a refund. I assume you are connecting the HDMI adapter/splitter cable to bottom Port A (which shows the keyboard+mouse symbols)? [Amazon page for model](https://www.amazon.com/CKL-Keyboard-Switcher-Computers-CKL-923HUA/dp/B07TD4ZTLB) indicates not drivers needed. [Official company page, needs translation](http://www.ckl.net.cn/cpzx/info_3_itemid_390.html)